# Ghost Cleanup Task not removing deleted rows, SQL2008 SP1 CU4

Tags: sql-server-2008

reaching out for any guidance for a problem I am seeing currently, one of my SQL servers is not releasing space after rows are deleted.

I am running SQL Server 2008 Enterprise x64 with SP1 CU4 (10.0.2734) and have a four node peer-peer replication configuration.

I am seeing large numbers records ready to be consumed by the ghost cleanup task via sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (ghost_record_count), however these counts do not decrease.

Strangely I am only experiencing this issue on one of the servers in the four node peer-peer configuration, that is the other three nodes successfully cleanup deleted rows with their respective ghost_record_counts eventually being reduced to zero.  The node that is experiencing this issue was the principal/initial node used to restore/setup the other nodes in the peer-peer replication topology.

I have tried both reorganizing and rebuilding the effected indexes, however this does not change the ghost_record_count figures after completion.  A full CHECKDB also does not yield any error/consistency issues.

Help? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have rebooted the offending server and the issue has resolved itself - the ghost-cleanup task has cleared the ghost_record_count rows by the next day :)  Database free space has increased dramatically.

I wouldn't say that the issue resolving itself after a reboot does much for my confidence as I do not know what lead to the problem, will need to keep an eye on the ghost_record_count's in my daily health-checks.